# Using rgbdslam with .oni files

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I needed to use the rgbd slam package with .oni files. After some hours of searching, I couldn't find any real help for this. Finally I figured out how to do it and it turned out that it's pretty simple. In fact, it's enough to add the following line to openni_nodelet.cpp:

*device_ = driver.createVirtualDevice("yourONIfile.oni",true/false,true/false);*

in the **OpenNINodelet::setupDevice** method as an alternative to the existing *getDeviceBy* options.

Finally, rebuild the openni_camera package (do not forget to move ROS_NOBUILD to ROS_NOBUILD_BAK or to delete it).

Hope this can be helpful!

Best

Axel Furlan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36487/using-rgbdslam-with-.oni-files/) by [Axel Furlan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2610/axel-furlan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-06-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

FYI, I used your proposal to create a patch for openni_camera, by applying the patch you can use the openni_launch toolchain and let the openni_camera nodelet read from an oni file:

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch device_id:=/path/to/your/file.oni
```

You can find the patch attached to this ticket: https://kforge.ros.org/openni/trac/ticket/60

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) with karma: 543 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Latif Anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/4454/latif-anjum/) on 2014-10-10**:
The patch link is not working. Can you provide a working link?